# Tracking App Install not working on Flutter app (Android) : CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I have implemented Firebase Analytics inside a Flutter app.

It's tracking fine all events but now I'm trying to add the Google Analytics receiver to track the source when the app is downloaded and successfully installed from the play store (coming from a link with campaign's parameters utm_source...)

In my Manifest I added these lines (inside the application tag):

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Then I tried to test following these steps: [Testing Google Play Campaign Measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns)

From the console the ADB returned:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.example.analyticsecommtest/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsReceiver (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

But when I run the installed app on the logcat I see:

```
CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled
```

Instead of:

```
Received installation campaign: source=testSource
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Is problem still there?
If no, then how did you solve that?

Comment: @Sp4Rx I answered my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution (at least for my case),

It's probably due to a lot of docs that can create confusion.

Using this:

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

solved the issue.

Comment: anything for iOS ? Can we get this source value in app and store/send it.

Comment: is there more configuration? only manifest? @Marco

Comment: @ghifari.akbar yes only the code above worked for me.